# Unable to remove listed background files in GPS Pathfinder Office

Tags: trimble, data-collection, pathfinder

I use GPS Pathfinder Office to send background data to a Trimble Geo7X unit prior to field data collection. Typically I don't have any problems with this, it simply involves adding the background files in quesiton (.shp's) to Pathfinder's list (pictured below with info censored) of background files, and then using the Data Transfer tool.

My problem is that I don't seem to have any way to REMOVE files off this list, since that button on the right is grayed out and so the list is starting to get a little long. It doesn't make a difference if I have one file checked in that window or all files checked, the button is always grayed. Has anyone else run into this problem?

I'm using a shared license with the rest of my company, but I can't imagine they would gate removing files behind a solo license... or at least I hope not. Also the user manual put out by Trimble does not mention this problem.

[image: GPS pathfinder office screenshot]

Comment: I think from memory you have to remove them individually, selecting them one at a time

Comment: It doesn't make a difference if I only check one or check all, the Remove button is always grayed out.

Comment: It's working now after I restarted the software. It's also possible that earlier I was only checking the files instead of selecting them (clicking on the name instead of checkbox). Hard to believe I didn't try that before but perhaps that's all it was. It's a bit unintuitive to have those actions split up from a design perspective, but at least it works. I'll leave this up so no one else makes the same mistake I did.